# autofill textformfield controller with condition

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, textformfield

im trying to make textformfield with condition in my controller. If the field is empty, it will be filled with the auto fill text that I have prepared. how to make condition in my textFormField controller?
below is my code.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  autofill = new TextEditingController(text: 'auto fill text');
  autofill2 = new TextEditingController(text: 'auto fill text2');
}
```

this is the variables.

```
final _key = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
TextEditingController autofill;
TextEditingController autofill2;
final first_nameController = TextEditingController();
final last_nameController = TextEditingController();
```

this is the validator to check if the field is empty, so the errorText will come out.

```
check() {
final form = _key.currentState;
if (form.validate()) {
  form.save();
  field();
}
}
```

this is my API connector to save text data form text field.

```
field() async {
String auto= autofill2.text;
String auto2= autofill.text;
String first_name = first_nameController.text;
String last_name = last_nameController.text;
// API URL
final response = await http.post(
  config.baseurl + "autofilltextformfield",
  body: {
    'first_name'.isEmpty ? first_name : auto,
    'last_name'.isEmpty ? last_name : auto2,
  },
);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  setState(
    () {
      visible = false;
    },
  );
}
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(response.body),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: new Text("OK"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
}
```

and this is the Field.

```
Form(
        key: _key,
child: TextFormField(
     validator: (e) {
         if (e.isEmpty) {
              return "please fill text";
         }
     },
     onSaved: (e) => first_nameController.text = e,
         style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
         ),
     controller: first_nameController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "text here",
                  hintStyle: _txtCustomSub,
                  enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 1.0,
                        style: BorderStyle.none),
                  ),
                ),
                autofocus: false,
              ),
InkWell(
    child: Text(
         "Save and Exit",
               style: _txtCustomHead,
    ),
    onTap: () {
        check();
    },
),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
autofill = new TextEditingController(text: 'auto fill text');
autofill2 = new TextEditingController(text: 'auto fill text2');
```

try:

```
first_nameController.text = 'auto fill text';
last_nameController.text = 'auto fill text2';
```